# autofill WebOTP javascript api is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, webapi, one-time-password

I've tried many sample codes but nothing works.

```
console.log("Otp.js>13 mounted");
if ('OTPCredential' in window) {
    try {
        console.log("Otp.js>16 in otpcredential");
        if (navigator.credentials) {
            try {
                console.log("Otp.js>19 credential");
                let {type,code} = await navigator.credentials.get({ otp:{ transport: ['sms']}})
                console.log("EsignSteps.js>78 aaaayo",type,code);
            }
            catch (e) {
                console.log("EsignSteps.js>81",e);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log("40",err);
    }
}
```

above code gives DOMException after few minutes even after I received OTP

I've also tried

```
const abort = new AbortController();

setTimeout(() => {
  abort.abort();
}, 2 * 60 * 1000);

let {type,code} = await navigator.credentials.get({ signal: abort.signal,otp:{ transport: ['sms']}})
```

Also tried

```
navigator.credentials.get({ signal: abort.signal,otp:{ transport: ['sms']}})
.then((otp)=>{
console.log(otp);
})
.catch(err=>{
console.log(err);
})
```

I've tried many sms formats like:

format 1:

```
Your OTP is : 123456
@https://example.com #123456
```

format 2:

```
Your OTP is : 123456
@example.com #123456
```

format 3:

```
Your OTP is : 123456
@www.example.com #123456
```

I've gone through smallest details of
https://web.dev/web-otp/

I've tried some demos like https://web-otp.glitch.me/, https://jyotishman.github.io/webOTPAPI/
which are not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I was sending the sms from my friend's mobile number which is saved in my contact list.
If the sender's phone number is included in the receiver's contact list, this API will not be triggered due to the design of the underlying [SMS User Consent API](https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/user-consent/request#2_start_listening_for_incoming_messages)!.